# How you can have to shuffle the questions from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, collections

Suppose if you have a questions like below image in firebase database.

[image]

```
database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
ArrayList<Question> questions;

        String categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("categoryId");  

           
        database.collection("categories")
                .document(categoryId)
                .collection("Questions")


                .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {


                    for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Question question = snapshot.toObject(Question.class);
                        questions.add(question);

                    }
                Collections.shuffle(questions);
}
});
```

In my case, I have a category (for example computer category, software category) and in each category we have a collection of questions Therefore we get a specific categoryId to display questions of specific category.
first you get all the question from database and add in a list like `questions.add(question);` if all the added in a list then you shuffle the questions in the list, `Collections.shuffle(questions);`
so each time you get different questions.